# Don't show the Product Detail Tab if empty (product detail)

Tags: product, attributes, products-view, tabs

My magento-product doesn't have any product detail infos (attributes) at my backend. But I see the empty "Product Detail Tab" on detail page. See screenshot.
How can I hide the Tabs in frontend. The Tabs are in my "catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml"

```
<?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
<?php
if (($showDescription && $_tab['alias'] == 'description') || $_tab['alias'] != 'description') {
    if (($showDetails && $_tab['alias'] == 'additional') || $_tab['alias'] != 'additional') {
        if (($showDetailsTab && $_tab['alias'] == 'additional_tab') || $_tab['alias'] != 'additional_tab') {
            if ($tmpBlock = $this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])) {
                $_panes .= '<h2 class="acctab" id="acctab-' . $_tab['alias'] . '">' . $_tab['title'] . '</h2>';
                $_panes .= '<div class="panel">' . $tmpBlock . '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

...

```
    <div id="product-tabs" class="gen-tabs gen-tabs-style1">

    <?php //IMPORTANT: id "product-tabs" is being used in: /catalog/product/view.phtml, /review/helper/summary*_nolinks.phtml   ?>
    <ul class="tabs clearer">
        <?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
            <?php if (($showDescription && $_tab['alias'] == 'description') || $_tab['alias'] != 'description'): ?>
                <?php if (($showDetails && $_tab['alias'] == 'additional') || $_tab['alias'] != 'additional'): ?>
                <?php if (($showDetailsTab && $_tab['alias'] == 'additional_tab') || $_tab['alias'] != 'additional_tab'): ?>
                    <?php if ($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
                        <li id="tab-<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>"><a href="#"><?php echo $_tab['title'] ?></a></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>  
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php echo $_extraTabs; //Append extra tabs after regular tabs ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs-panels"><?php echo $_panes, $_extraPanes; //Append extra panels to regular panels     ?></div>

</div>
```

[image: show product details (attributes), but its empty?!]

Answer (score 4):

The code in `tabs.phtml` looks like this:

```
<ul class="product-tabs">
    <?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
        <?php if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
            <li id="product_tabs_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>" class="<?php echo !$_index?' active first':(($_index==count($this->getTabs())-1)?' last':'')?>"><a href="#"><?php echo $_tab['title']?></a></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
    <?php if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
        <div class="product-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>_contents"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias']) ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So if a tab content is empty then the tab is not shown.
Either you have a different code, or your tab content is not empty. It may contain something like `<div></div>` or something like that.
In this case you can change the `if` statement to remove your tags.
Maybe something like this:

```
<ul class="product-tabs">
    <?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
        <?php if(trim(strip_tags($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])))): ?>
            <li id="product_tabs_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>" class="<?php echo !$_index?' active first':(($_index==count($this->getTabs())-1)?' last':'')?>"><a href="#"><?php echo $_tab['title']?></a></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
<?php foreach ($this->getTabs() as $_index => $_tab): ?>
    <?php if(trim(strip_tags($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])))): ?>
        <div class="product-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_<?php echo $_tab['alias'] ?>_contents"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias']) ?></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I use the ultimo theme. my code looks a bit different?! see my question, I've edit it and post my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `trim(strip_tags()` in both if condition under foreach loop.

Below code tested in ultimo theme.

change line no 11

```
if($tmpBlock = $this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias']))
```

to

```
if($tmpBlock = trim(strip_tags($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias']))))
```

and line no 35

```
<?php if($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])): ?>
```

to

```
 <?php if(trim(strip_tags($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])))): ?>
```

Hope, it will be help.

Comment: change line 35  with <?php if(trim(strip_tags($this->getChildHtml($_tab['alias'])))): ?>

Comment: I've tried this solution however it removes all of the styling and what not within the other tabs.. any ideas?

Comment: are you using ultimo theme?

Comment: Yes I am, and it turns out if your tab content is empty, ultimo will automatically hide it, so I removed the text I was saving for if there was no details anyway, and it worked out. Thanks!